# WiX Source Files In a Different Directory From the Project File

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wix, votive

I'm building an installer for a Visual Studio 2010 solution and I've decided to go with WiX. I've added the WiX setup project to the solution and am trying to configure it in a similar fashion to the rest of the projects in the solution.

The way those projects are setup is that their project files are in a seperate directory from the rest of the source:

```
Source
    Core
    UI
    Projects <- .vcproj files for the Core and UI projects are in this directory
    ...
```

Now the new project for the WiX installer is called Setup so the directory tree now looks like:

```
Source
    Core
    UI
    Setup
    Projects <- .wixproj for Setup is here, and I want it's source files in the Setup directory
    ...
```

The problem is that whenever I add a source file to the Setup project, it copies the file from where it is to the Projects directory, next to the .wixproj file.

Is there something I can set on the project to prevent this behaviour and include WiX source files in-place?

Comment: You need to add the file as a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593612/visual-studio-add-item-add-as-link-rather-than-just-add

Comment: Thanks Bryan, that works for me. Easy to miss since normally when I add files to other project types they're automatically referenced from their current location rather than copied. Is this link method the only way to add files from their current locations to WiX projects?

Comment: You could also open the .wixproj in an xml editor and add the files by editing the xml (see how the other files you linked to the project appear). That seems more complicated, but may be less tedious if you have a very large number of source files to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Bryan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14362840/wix-source-files-in-a-different-directory-from-the-project-file/14370424#comment19972958_14362840) basically covered it:

> You could also open the .wixproj in an xml editor and add the files by editing the xml (see how the other files you linked to the project appear). That seems more complicated, but may be less tedious if you have a very large number of source files to add.