# C# project how to use cs file from another path？

Tags: c#

My workspace folder is `MySpace`.
project demo1 path is `MySpace/demo1`.
project demo2 path is `MySpace/demo2`.
the common cs file path is `MySpace/common`.

Now, i want use MySpace/common/StringUtils.cs in project demo1.
and i donnot want to gen the common.dll, means just one exe per project, is demo1.exe and demo2.exe.
Kindly give me your advice, very thanks.

Comment: If you want a single output executable, why not statically-link your assemblies using `ILMerge`?

Comment: Anyway, what you want is "Add linked file": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593612/visual-studio-add-item-add-as-link-rather-than-just-add

Comment: Thanks @Dai  , that would solve my problem.
But it is not grace, because ILMerge is cat the two pe file.
And i want solve it as C/C++ can do, #include "../common", in this way, the compiler include the need file to  compile in real.

Answer (score 1):

- Right-click the project, select Add->Existing Item.
- Select the files.
- Choose Add as link.

And thanks @Dai a lot for given the answer link.

The picture below is from @Fka, and thanks a lot.

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ot822.png)

[picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8PUq.png)